# How to set up a var to link different stylesheets based on data entered in the var

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to pull a different style sheet based on the var I manually enter, how do I do that?

```
varDivision = "" //SET TOTAL NUMBER OF DIVISIONS IN YOUR LEAGUE
varTeams = ""    //ENTER TOTAL NUMBER OF TEAMS IN YOUR LEAGUE 

if 1 division 5 teams link this stylesheet "url"
if 1 division 6 teams link this stylesheet "url"
if 2 divisions 10 teams link this stylesheet "url"
if 3 divisions 12 teams link this stylesheet "url"
```

And so on. I can list out each possibility...

Comment: You can append the right style on your head element with an if statement.

Comment: This is possible, but do you really need a different style sheet? It might be easier to change one class on a root element and load just one style sheet normally.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert the `<link/>` element in the `<head/>` section

```
$('head')
.find('*[data-dynamicCss="true"]').remove()
.append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" data-dynamicCss="true" />')
.attr('href', 'your stylesheet url') );
```